# how to using spoiler code in looping

Tags: javascript, php, html, loops, foreach

is that posible using spoiler in looping?
i try create like this but fail
when i click spoiler toogle nothing happening.

```
    foreach ($data as $key=>$value): ?>
<td style="padding-bottom: 0px;padding-top: 0px; border-top-width: 0px; width: 13%;" align="right">
    <div class="spoiler">
      <div class="spoiler-toggle">480p<div>
    </td>
        <td style="padding-bottom: 0px;padding-top: 0px; border-top-width: 0px; width: 13%;" align="right">720p</td>
        <td style="padding-bottom: 0px;padding-top: 0px; border-top-width: 0px; width: 13%;" align="right">1080p</td>
```

here for spoiler text,.

```
    <div class="spoiler-text">
<table class="table table-hover">
    <tbody style="border-top-width: 0px;">
    <tr>
    <td style="padding-bottom: 0px;padding-top: 0px; border-top-width: 0px;" align="left">
    <div class"tes" style="text-decoration: none; font-style: italic;"><u style="border-bottom: 1px dotted #000;text-decoration: none;"><?php echo $value['judul']?></u> - <?php echo $value['episodes'] ?> [480p]</div>
     </td>
    <td style="padding-bottom: 0px;padding-top: 0px; border-top-width: 0px;" align="right">
     <?php echo html_entity_decode ($value['480p'] ); ?>
     </td>
     </tr>
     </tbody>
     </table></div></div><?php endforeach; ?>
```

my javascript

```
<script>
          $(function(){
    $('.spoiler-text').hide();
    $('.spoiler-toggle').click(function(){
        $(this).next().toggle();
    }); // end spoiler-toggle
}); // end document ready
        </script>
```

full script https://github.com/jazuly/ahp/blob/master/spoiler.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This HTML is not valid:

```
<td style="padding-bottom: 0px;padding-top: 0px; border-top-width: 0px; width: 13%;" align="right">
    <div class="spoiler">
      <div class="spoiler-toggle">480p<div>
    </td>
```

Also, your `$(this).next()` never finds next. `.spoiler-text` should be a next sibling to `.spoiler-toggle`